# WinSCP alternative for Ubuntu

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, file-synchronization, ftp

I've always used WinSCP for Windows to keep my directories up to date with the sync option. This is a really useful feature that most FTP clients lack.

Now I started programming on Ubuntu and, since there's no WinSCP version for this OS I'm searching for an alternative.

Is there any other FTP software with this /keepuptodate option which works for Linux?

Comment: Not acquainted with WinSCP ... is that some kind of a service that synchronizes in the background ?

Comment: @pLumo it is an [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) client. In simple words, it sends files from a local computer to a remote server and it is used by web developers to update their website pages. The advantage of [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) is that you can keep your local folder and the server syncronized without the need to manually transfer each file. This service is not offered by other FTP clients like FileZilla

Comment: my question was if this function is a service that always runs in background?

Comment: @pLumo yes, it runs in the background and syncs files based on their *last modified date*

Comment: Ever heard about `rsync`? Even ships with Ubuntu – and especially thought for keeping things in sync. You could even schedule a cron job to have it run periodically. Can use different protocols; by default it uses RSH, most people use it with SSH. It probably supports more (but that's all I use it with).

Comment: @Izzy, but does WinSCP sync by timer or does it listen to filesystem messages? If listens then doing it by cron won't be the best analogue.

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, never tried to *sync* stuff with WinSCP – so I cannot tell how WinSCP handles this. AFAIK rsync compares timestamps to see which files to deal with. Didn't really dig into that: it worked for me, so I didn't ask "why" (one usually starts asking "why" when something stops working, not before ;)

Comment: WinSCP can do both. The OP seems to refers to ["Keep remote directory up date" function](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date), which listens to OS notifications about file system changes.